# average method won't run correctly

Tags: java

This is my average method that I am trying to obtain some values from.

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code, but it won't compile correctly.

I am actually not getting any output from it.

I also need to know hoe to call this method from the main method.  Thanks!

```
public String averageFood()
    {
String averageStuff = "";
        double avg = 0;
        double num1 = 0;
        double num2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numGerbils; i++)
        {
            averageStuff = averageStuff + gerbilArray[i].getID();
            averageStuff = averageStuff + " (";
            averageStuff = averageStuff + gerbilArray[i].getName();
            averageStuff = averageStuff + ") ";
            for (int k = 0; k < foodnum; k++)
            {
                num1 = num1 + foodArray[k].getamtOfFood();
                num2 = num2 + gerbilArray[i].getGerbFood()[k].getamtOfFood();
            }
            avg = 100*(num2/num1);
            avg = Math.round(avg);
            averageStuff = averageStuff + Double.toString(avg);
            averageStuff = averageStuff + "%\n";
        }
        return averageStuff;
    }
```

public class Gerbil {

```
String ID;
String name;
//private int[] consumption;
boolean bite; 
boolean escape;
Food[] gerbFood;
int sum;

//public Gerbil (int numOfFood) {

    //consumption = new int[numOfFood];
//}

public Gerbil(String ID, String name, boolean bite, boolean escape, Food[] gerbFood)
{

    this.ID = ID;
    this.name = name;
    this.bite = bite;
    this.escape = escape;
    this.gerbFood = gerbFood;

}

public String getID() {
    return ID;

}


//public void setID(String Id) {
    //Id = ID;
//}

public String getName () {
    return name;
}

public Food[] getGerbFood() {
    return gerbFood;
}

//public void setName (String name) {
    //this.name = name;
//}

//public int[] getConsumption () {
    //return consumption;
//}
public String getBite() {
    if(bite == true) {
        return "will bite";
    }
    else {
        return "will not bite";
    }

}
//public void setBite(boolean bite) {
    //this.bite = bite;
//}

public String getEscape() {
    if(escape == true) {
    return "will escape";
    }
    else {
        return "won't escape";
    }
}
```

public class Food {

```
String nameOfFood;
String colorOfFood;
int amtOfFood;

public Food (String nameOfFood, String colorOfFood, int amtOfFood)
{
    this.nameOfFood = nameOfFood;
    this.colorOfFood = colorOfFood;
    this.amtOfFood = amtOfFood;
}

public String getnameOfFood()
{
    return nameOfFood;
}

public String getcolorOfFood()
{
    return colorOfFood;
}

public int getamtOfFood()
    {
    return amtOfFood;
    }
}
```

Comment: What compiler errors are you getting?

Comment: I'll take a guess that this is a variable scope issue; did you perhaps declare the girbil stuff in main? It will need to be static class variables, or you need to pass them to the function as parameters.

Comment: Also you should really be using a StringBuilder

Comment: if (prompt.equalsIgnoreCase("average"))
    {
     System.out.println(averageFood());
    }

Comment: ^^ that's how I called it from the main?

Comment: That call is fine for the function you posted here, but as I say you probably need to pass your variables to it. Can't say much without seeing the compiler error though.

Comment: There's actually no error, that's what I am so confused by.  It just ignores the user input and prompts the user for a function again.  here's the link to my full code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175941/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main

Comment: You said it won't compile.  Was that incorrect?

Comment: you have already the answer

Comment: Yeah I guess compile was the wrong term to use.  The code is probably incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Yes remove -> ``

You can call that method in main like that:

String someString = avrageFood();

Comment: It is unclear what the backtick characters have to do with the asker's code. Could you clarify which line you are suggesting to be modified?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough of your code to give you a good answer.

We need to see the rest of the class that `averageFood()` is in (I'll call it 'Foo'). *If `averageFood()` is not in a class, then that is one of your problems.*

1. There are many variables that are not defined locally by your method. Are they members of Foo?:

   - numGerbils
   - gerbilArray
   - foodnum
   - foodArray
2. `main()` is a `static` method, but `averageFood()` is a *non-static* method. Therefore, `main()` cannot directly call `averageFood()` -- it needs to access that method through a Foo instance, like this:

`public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.averageFood();
    }`

If you continue to have problems, then please show *all* your code.

Comment: if you follow this link then it will show you all of my code including the main method and all of the defined variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175941/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main

Comment: The main problems in that code are that the Gerbil and Food classes are undefined. You need to try to understand all your compiler errors. This site may be helpful: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/compileerrormessages.html

Comment: No I have the gerbil and food classes as well, I can post them to this forum, hold on.

Comment: But your code is not importing them? If they are not defined in the same file (and do not belong to the same package), then they have to be imported.

Comment: both gerbil and food classes are posted above. when the user types in "average" for the program to run the averageFood method, the user is prompted this message again --> "Which function would you like to carry out: average, search, restart, or quit?" instead of carrying out the average method and outputting the average itself

Comment: In gerLab(), you are assigning to *local variables* named 'foodnum' and 'numGerbils', which are hiding the instance variables with the same names. Therefore, the instance variables are always 0, and averageFood() just returns an empty string.

For example, "final int numGerbils = ..." is defining a local variable; it should be "numGerbils = ...", instead.